# Multiple columns to int

Tags: pandas

I have the following data that I am working with:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/population.csv"
bevdf2 = pd.read_csv(url)
```

I would like to change multiple files from object to integer. I have recently discovered the  `.loc` and would like to put it to use:

```py
aus = bevdf2.iloc[:, 39:75]
    
bevdf2[aus] = bevdf2[aus].astype(int)
```

but I get this output:

```
Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

Is there a simple to continue with the `.loc` tool to convert the multiple columns to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is some invalid values like `-`, `/` so first convert them to missing values by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and if need convert floats to integers use [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) (pandas 0.24+):

```
bevdf2.iloc[:,  39:75] = (bevdf2.iloc[:,  39:75]
                                .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
                                .astype('Int64'))
```

---

```
print (bevdf2.iloc[:,  39:75].dtypes)
deu50    Int64
aus15    Int64
aus16    Int64
aus17    Int64
aus18    Int64
aus19    Int64
aus20    Int64
aus21    Int64
aus22    Int64
aus23    Int64
aus24    Int64
aus25    Int64
aus26    Int64
aus27    Int64
aus28    Int64
aus29    Int64
aus30    Int64
aus31    Int64
aus32    Int64
aus33    Int64
aus34    Int64
aus35    Int64
aus36    Int64
aus37    Int64
aus38    Int64
aus39    Int64
aus40    Int64
aus41    Int64
aus42    Int64
aus43    Int64
aus44    Int64
aus45    Int64
aus46    Int64
aus47    Int64
aus48    Int64
aus49    Int64
dtype: object
```